# Only using low side of high/low mosfet driver - can I leave the high pins disconnected?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver, half-bridge

I have the below circuit for a high/low mosfet driver half bridge, with an extra low side for running a brake resistor (note this is just one of the 3 half bridges for the BLDC controller)

I'm using the same high/low driver for the extra low side, and feeding the logic the same high side signal as the main driver to get the benefit of the shoot through protection.

As I am not using the high side gate driver can I leave BOOT HVG and OUT disconnected? If they shouldn't be left disconnect then what should I connect them to?

See red circled area on

[image: Circuit diagram]

Layout of the driver chip

[image: L6388E block diagram]